# Multi-label text classification using mlr package in R

Tags: multilabel-classification, mlr

I need to train a model which would perform multilabel multiclass classification on text data.

I am presently trying to do the same using mlr package in R , following the directions in this link -

[Multilabel Classification (using mlr R package)](http://[http://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/devel/html/multilabel/index.html][1])

1) Is there any other package recommended?

2) Otherwise, I am stuck at this place (as instructed in the article mentioned above)

```
classify <-  getTaskData(dtmDf) ## dtmDf is my dtm converted to dataframe   form
```

'classify' is NULL

Any help/ directions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Updates:- 
Trying to create the 'task' object . Code as below-

```
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs) 
mat <- as.matrix(dtm)
mat <- cbind(mat,data$Label)

dtmDf <- as.data.frame(mat)
target <- unique(dtmDf[,2628]) %>% as.character() %>% sort()

classify.task = makeMultilabelTask(id = "classif", data = dtmDf, target =target)
```

Face the following error -

Error in makeSupervisedTask("multilabel", data, target, weights, blocking) : 
  Column names of data doesn't contain target var: 10

**SOLVED**

I was able to train it after getting the input data frame in the required format , similar to the yeast data in the tutorial link, which was given as input to the makeMultilabelTask() function

Comment: You need to create an mlr task to use `getTaskData()`. See [the tutorial](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/devel/html/task/index.html).

Comment: @Lars, yes , in the process of creating the task- met with a dead end there. I get the following error    -                                                                                                  Error in makeSupervisedTask("multilabel", data, target, weights, blocking) : 
  Column names of data doesn't contain target var:

Comment: How to create a task is described in the tutorial I've linked to. Does this not work for you? How does it not work?

Comment: @Lars - updated the question with the info.Thanks

Comment: The target argument to `makeMultiLabelTask()` should be the list of column names that contain the target values, not the target values themselves.

Comment: I dont get the format in which my input should be in that case. Right now its a dtm , with the features ( words) as the column names. I added the last column to contain the class/labels against each document.                                                                         The tutorial has data in .arff format which I am not familiar with. I will try to figure out that part now.

Comment: It sounds like that last column is your target then.

Comment: The expected input format is different,as I understand after looking at the "yeast" data. Will update here , if I succeed in getting it right. Thank you!