# Text Categorization by uisng mlr package in R

Tags: r, random-forest, multilabel-classification, mlr

I need to train a model which would perform multilabel multiclass categorization on text data.

Currently, i'm using mlr package in R. But unluckily I didn't proceed further because of the error I got it before training a model.

More specifically I'm stuck in this place:

```
classify.task = makeMultilabelTask(id = "classif", data = termsDf, target =target)
```

and, got this error

> Error in makeMultilabelTask(id = "classif", data = termsDf, target = target) : 
>     Assertion on 'data' failed: Columns must be named according to R's variable naming conventions and may not contain special characters.

I used this example: - 
[Multi-label text classification using mlr package in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332849/multi-label-text-classification-using-mlr-package-in-r)

Here is a complete code snippet i'm using so far,

```
tm <- read.csv("translate_text_V02.csv", header = TRUE, 
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = c("", "NA")) 
process <- tm[, c("label", "text")]

    process <- na.omit(process)
    docs <- Corpus(VectorSource(process$text))
    clean_corpus <- function(corpus){
      corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
      corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
      corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
      corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, mystopwords)
      corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("SMART"))
      corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("german"))
      corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
      corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stemDocument, language = "english")
      return(corpus)
    }
    clean_corp <- clean_corpus(docs)
    terms <-DocumentTermMatrix(clean_corp)
    m <- as.matrix(terms)
    m <- cbind(m,process$label)
    termsDf <- as.data.frame(m)
    target <- unique(termsDf[,2628]) %>% as.character() %>% sort()
    classify.task = makeMultilabelTask(id = "classif", data = termsDf, target =target)
```

I created the data frame after Document term matrix with the label class. but I'm stuck afterwords how can I proceed further with machine learning part?

Questions for kind answer: -

1. How can I proceed further with the creation of DocumentTermMatrix?
2. How to apply the random-forest algorithm on this particular dataset?

Comment: As the error messages says, you need to rename the columns to conform to R's naming conventions, e.g. `names(termsDf) = lapply(names(termsDf), as.name)`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, Error is still there. even by using the command mentioned above I got the same error.

Comment: We need to see the data to be able to help you.

Comment: Below mentioned text example is used for the classification task.  So, kindly do let me know how I can train through machine learning algorithms by using a below-mentioned example?


Company, Country, Region, vertical_market, website, text
ZF Friedrichshafen AG, Germany, Europe, Automotive, www....com, text get from the first page of each website

Comment: Maybe try the following: `colnames(termsDf) = make.names(colnames(termsDf))`

Comment: Can you post a complete example (with data) that allows to reproduce the problem please?

Comment: @PhilippPro, Now I got this error. "Error in makeSupervisedTask("multilabel", data, target, weights, blocking) : 
  Column names of data doesn't contain target var: 0"

Comment: Is 0 a name in your `target` vector? The colnames should ideally be real names (e.g.`c("target1", "target2", "var3", "var4")`) and the target is a character vector that specify the target vectors (e.g. `c("target1", "target2")`)

Comment: @PhilippPro, thank you for your guidance. There was issue in my corpus such as; long word. But I even applied NLP procedures before creating a machine learning algorithms, but still, the problem is there. I create an algorithm to take only words no longer than 16 characters so, now machine learning algorithm is working but giving my 42% accuracy by using 'ranger' mlr package. If you have an idea how can I improve the efficiency of this model. Kindly guide me.